# SQLite3 increment partial key sequence

Tags: sqlite, key, partial

I'm trying to create an incrementing column in SQLite to keep information in the order it exists in an imported text log and grouped by item.

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    row INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    item TEXT,
    info TEXT
);
```

Using the following table, I'd like to automatically increment "seq" relative to "item".

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    item TEXT,
    seq  INTEGER,
    info TEXT,
   CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY (item, seq)
);
```

I've tried various INSERTs and continually get UNIQUE/CONSTRAINT violations:

```
INSERT INTO test (item, seq, info)
   SELECT item, (SELECT count(item) FROM test t WHERE l.item=t.item) + 1, info 
FROM log l;

INSERT INTO test (item, seq, info)
   SELECT item, (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(seq),0)+1 FROM test t WHERE l.item=t.item), info 
FROM log l;
```

When I remove the CONSTRAINT to see the results, "seq" always ends up 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're counting rows with the same `item` value in the `test` table, but that table is not yet filled.

Just count rows in the `log` table instead.
Because you see all rows, but want only previous rows, you must add another filter (if you don't have something like a timestamp, use the `rowid`):

```
..., (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM log AS l2
      WHERE l2.item   = l.item
        AND l2.rowid <= l.rowid)), ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a simple example of my original problem, which was combining data from 2 tables (joined) with a sequence, limited to items in a 3rd table.